# Why is the callback URL for Google Docs failing to work with Tumblr API?

Tags: javascript, oauth, google-apps-script, tumblr, google-sheets

I've written the following Google Apps Script function to authorise a Google Spreadsheet to query the Tumblr API v2 (which uses Oauth 1.0a).

I've tried a few variants of the callback URL - I've successfully used https://spreadsheets.google.com/macros/ with the Twitter API - but after clicking Authorize on the Authorize page, the callback URL redirects to **www.google.com/script/start/** and doesn't authenticate.

Here's the script I've been trying - any thoughts on why this might not work?

```
function authorise() {
  var oauthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService("tumblr");
  oauthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("http://www.tumblr.com/oauth/access_token");
  oauthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("http://www.tumblr.com/oauth/request_token");
  oauthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("http://www.tumblr.com/oauth/authorize");
  oauthConfig.setConsumerKey(tumblrKey);
  oauthConfig.setConsumerSecret(tumblrSecret);
  var requestData = {
    "method": "GET",
    "oAuthServiceName": "tumblr",
    "oAuthUseToken": "always"
  }
  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(
      "http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/frankocean.com/info",
      requestData);
    Logger.log(result.getContentText());
}
```

Comment: Same issue here. Works fine with Twitter but Tumblr fails...

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem with OAuth 1.0a.

To solve it I used RestClient addon in firefox to track down the cause.

The problem turned out to be requestData, the OAuth was working, but the fetch was being rejected because the requestData was wrong.

[Edit]
for twitter:

```
var requestData = {
  "method": "POST",
  "oAuthServiceName": "twitter",
  "oAuthUseToken": "always"
};
```

for QuickBooks:

```
var requestData = {
"method": "GET",
"oAuthServiceName": "QuickBooks",
"oAuthUseToken": "always"
```

};

Comment: What was the specific problem you had with requestData? I'm having a play now, but can't seem to find any problems as yet…

Comment: Tom, hope it helps, see above - note one uses GET not POST